# JQuery "click" not triggering function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm trying to trigger a JQuery function when you click on a div (i've tried making it a button as well) to no avail. Google Chrome Inspector does not even recognize an event handler being created behind the scenes.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">;
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "main" style = "width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: black; color: white;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius aliquam nobis optio ut ratione a eligendi excepturi cumque est commodi? Sed, odit, culpa deserunt distinctio at commodi modi architecto aliquam.
        </div>
        <button class = "button" href="#" style = "width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black;"></button>
        <script type = "text/javacsript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".button").click(function(){
                    $("main").val("IT WORKED");
                });
            };
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(` at the end of the document is a bit belt and suspenders isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use `#` for id selector, also use `text()` or `html()` instead of val() for `div` and you also missed the closing parenthesis of `document.ready`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/HEAbC/)**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".button").click(function(){
           $("#main").text("IT WORKED");
     });
  });
```

Comment: oddly enough, copy pasting your code puts an additional semicolon on the screend